# ASP.NET WebForms - Calling an Async method from a WebPart method

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, webforms

I realize there are several articles written around this topic, but from what I've seen there are several different recommendations depending on the scenario you encounter. I am working with a project that is using Azure B2C to authenticate individual web parts using the following code

```cs
public class AdaptorPart : WebPart {
  protected override void CreateChildControls() {
    //...
    var owinContext = Context.GetOwinContext();
    var result = owinContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("cookie").Result;
    var idToken = result.Properties.Dictionary[OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken];
    //...
  }
}
```

The project is finding that there is thread starvation and a crash happening randomly. A `NullReferenceException` is occurring on the `result` object just before this happens. I am concerned that the blocking `.Result` property could be contributing to this problem, so I was thinking that we could use a different non-blocking call to achieve the same result. However, mixing these concepts seems like a hard problem without in depth understanding and there's a good chance I'm going to still do something wrong. I came up with two different ideas, but not sure if these are the right choices, or if there is a better method.

The first idea was to just use a `Task.Run` like the following, but I am concerned about this based on warnings of using context objects:

```cs
string idToken;
Task.Run(async () => {
    var result =
        await owinContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("cookie");
    idToken = result?.Properties?.Dictionary[OpenIdConnectParameterNames?.IdToken];
});
// if (idToken == null) return error
```

The second thought was to use a library to wrap the call which would look like this:

```cs
var result = Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
    await owinContext.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync("cookie"));
var idToken = result?.Properties?.Dictionary[OpenIdConnectParameterNames?.IdToken];
// if (idToken == null) return error
```

How would you, or how have you, implemented a solution that has proven to work at scale and what makes you certain it will work?